# Add Bootstrap to a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, function, bootstrap-4

I am creating a form dynamically whenever a button is pressed but I don't know how to add Bootstrap for this form element.

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
 f.setAttribute('method',"post");

  var i = document.createElement("input");
  i.setAttribute('type',"text");
  i.setAttribute('name',"username");

  var s = document.createElement("input");
  s.setAttribute('type',"submit");
  s.setAttribute('value',"Submit");

  f.appendChild(i);
  f.appendChild(s);

  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
```

Comment: Make appropriate structure and add appropriate classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the attribute class

```
s.setAttribute('class',"btn btn-success");
```

Comment: No i want link it with <link rel='stylesheet' src='....bootstrap.min.css'>

Comment: if you have linked bootstrap to your html structure, the class you set take that prop from bootstrap.min.css, can you provide more datails?

Comment: great! please mark the answer like useful, to this way helps others members :D